# Using Templates to add virtual tables to non-virtual classes

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

So I have these classes that are meant to be low level and fast. I don't want them to generally be virtual - rather I want the functions to be inline.

In this case they are mutex implementations:

```
class MutexOne
{
public:
   void lock        () { /* implementation inline */ }   
   bool tryLock     () { /* implementation inline */ }  
   void unlock      () { /* implementation inline */ }
   void reset       () { /* implementation inline */ }

   static const char* implementationName() { return "MutexOne"; }
};

class MutexTwo
{
public:
   void lock        () { /* implementation inline */ }   
   bool tryLock     () { /* implementation inline */ }  
   void unlock      () { /* implementation inline */ }
   void reset       () { /* implementation inline */ }

   static const char* implementationName() { return "MutexTwo"; }
};

... etc ...
```

All the mmutexes have the same api. Within a testing framework I kind of wish they were virtual so that I can do something like:

```
testMutexImplementation( MutexVirtual& mutex )
{
    mutex.lock();  // etc... do a lot of complex validating
}
```

So within the testing framework I wish I had a nice clean virtual base class interface. But in production I don't want to pay for a virtual function on every mutex operation many of which are like 2-3 opcode in the general case.

So I thought of this way to use templates to add a virtual table after the fact, only when I need it.

So I start by creating the desired base class:

```
class MutexVirtual
{
public:

   virtual void lock        () = 0;
   virtual bool tryLock     () = 0;
   virtual void unlock      () = 0;
   virtual void reset       () = 0; 

   virtual const char* implementationName() = 0;
};
```

And then use template magic to fill in the virtual table:

```
template < typename T > class MutexPostVirtual : public MutexVirtual, public T
{
public:
   void lock           () { T::lock(); }
   bool tryLock        () { return T::tryLock(); }
   void unlock         () { T::unlock(); }
   void reset          () { T::reset(); } 

   const char* implementationName() { return T::implementationName(); }
};
```

I'm pretty happy and it works great:

```
MutexPostVirtual<MutexOne> mutex1;
MutexPostVirtual<MutexTwo> mutex2;

testMutexImplementation( mutex1 );
testMutexImplementation( mutex2 );
```

I can't help thinking that maybe there is a cleaner simpler way? How can this code be better?

Comment: If they all share the same interface, why not just make `testMutexImplementation()` a template function?

Comment: That would work in many cases - where the complexity of what is inside  testMutexImplementation is low. But this function actually gets quite complex inside - spawning threads that have thread functions that can't be templatized.

Comment: This is my real code. I removed the portions that are not relevant to the question (e.g. mutex implementation details) and renamed the classes to example names - since its the pattern of multiple classes that matters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what framework you are using for your tests but gtest has [type parametrised tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#typed-tests) that you can use to test all the implementations​ with the same tests.

By using this feature you wouldn't even need the code to begin with, which in my book is the best code: the code you never wrote :)

Comment: Thats a great testing framework - but not really relevant to my question. The question is about a good way to add virtual tables "after the fact" rather than about creating a good testing framework.

Comment: It's not about creating a good testing framework it's about avoiding the issue of having to create the vtable after the fact to begin with, which I consider a code smell.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista Some times the answer to the question: "How can this code be better?", is simply "By not being at all." I believe that this is the case here. Use the right tool for the job.